# Angular recursive component prevent sharing properties

Tags: javascript, angular, recursion, tree, components

I have a recursive component to create a dynamically updating tree structure which can be collapsed. However, it seems that the `active` variable which determines the state is shared with child components. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-og-span',
  templateUrl: './og-span.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./og-span.component.css']
})
export class OgSpanComponent  {
  @Input() comments;
  private isActive = true;

  toggleActive($event) {
    console.log('wtf');
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    $event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
<div class="ui accordion" style="padding-left: 15px" *ngFor="let comment of comments">
  <div class="title" [ngClass]="{'active': isActive}" (click)="toggleActive($event);$event.stopPropagation()">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    {{comment.text}}
  </div>
  <div class="content" [ngClass]="{'active': isActive}">
    <app-og-span [comments]="comment.comments" *ngIf="comment.comments"></app-og-span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know the event is fired only once from logs. There was a case of variable scopes with AngularJS (1.x) but I cannot find to find the corresponding in 6 (2+)

Comment: It's not shared. You miss something. Could you provide more details about issue?

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr yep you are right I assumed it was and was blinded by my prejudice :( added

Comment: @Mustafa, isActive can not be "private", therefore you needn't $event.stopPropagation() or return=false

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was wrong changing the code to following worked, because I placed **the *ngFor** wrongly at the top to get the view I wanted but not semantically correct one (and I assumed the AngularJS 1.x case of variable scopes):

```
<div class="ui styled accordion" style="padding-left: 10px">
  <div class="title" (click)="click($event)" [ngClass]="{'active': active}">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    {{ node.name }}
  </div>
  <div class="content" [ngClass]="{'active': active}">
    <span *ngFor="let node of node.children">
      <app-og-span [node]="node"></app-og-span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-og-span',
  templateUrl: './og-span.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./og-span.component.css']
})
export class OgSpanComponent {
  @Input() node;
  private active = true;

  click($event) {
    this.active = !this.active;
    $event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```